# Different Android Phone Uses Different Encoding?

Tags: java, android, http, http-get

I am developing an app plays song and communicates with a server. The methods are `addMusic`, `deleteMusic`, and `requestMusicList`. All of them uses http GET method.

**Here's The Case:**

`deleteMusic`, and `requestMusicList` works fine in all phones. Except for `addMusic`, which only works in some phone.

`addMusic` only works in Samsung phone. While in nuu, mi, and meizu. Those are the phones that we got here, so we only tested the app with those phones.

**My Problem:**

Since the parameters included in the `addMusic` url string contains Chinese characters, I think this is the cause of the problem. Here is the log.

```
08-06 15:00:22.102: V/HttpConnectionManager(13211): Get url string is http://115.28.6.88:7100/cgi-bin/v1/music_add?content_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group12/M07/03/65/wKgDW1VQa-6iJ2e1AB7JjcEKs2E684.mp3&cover_image_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group11/M02/03/7B/wKgDa1VQbA2j2mOpAAiTLl27BzM875_mobile_small.jpg&dev_id=test101&duration=252&timestamp=1438844422&title=《Couldyoustaywithme》张靓颖（电视剧《洋嫁》主题曲）&type=type_habit&sign=f834a4667004cebdac1516584b4a4930

08-06 15:00:22.272: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13211): <ConfigWindowMatch:2252>: Format RGBA_8888.

08-06 15:00:22.342: V/HttpConnectionManager(13211): Response code from GET: 200

08-06 15:00:22.352: V/DetailManager(13211): Handled http response is {"retcode": 100004, "retinfo": "check sign fail, request_sign:[F834A4667004CEBDAC1516584B4A4930], mysign:[EBFA4D2D40F20DF1B124375A0D9FAD38], mysign_src_nokey:[content_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group12/M07/03/65/wKgDW1VQa-6iJ2e1AB7JjcEKs2E684.mp3&cover_image_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group11/M02/03/7B/wKgDa1VQbA2j2mOpAAiTLl27BzM875_mobile_small.jpg&dev_id=test101&duration=252&timestamp=1438844422&title=?Couldyoustaywithme????????????????&type=type_habit]"}

08-06 15:00:22.352: V/AudioFragment(13211): Server request failed: check sign fail, request_sign:[F834A4667004CEBDAC1516584B4A4930], mysign:[EBFA4D2D40F20DF1B124375A0D9FAD38], mysign_src_nokey:[content_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group12/M07/03/65/wKgDW1VQa-6iJ2e1AB7JjcEKs2E684.mp3&cover_image_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group11/M02/03/7B/wKgDa1VQbA2j2mOpAAiTLl27BzM875_mobile_small.jpg&dev_id=test101&duration=252&timestamp=1438844422&title=?Couldyoustaywithme????????????????&type=type_habit]
```

As can be seen in the first line, this contains the URL that I sent. The URL contains these "张靓颖（电视剧《洋嫁》主题曲" Chinese characters under the title parameter. When the server returns a response, these characters became "??????????????".

Please take not that this issue only occurs in the said Android phones(mi, meizu, and nuu). For **Samsung**, this **NEVER** occured.

Here is the code of my addMusic method:

```
public void addMusic(final Music music)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            String contentURL = KEY_CONTENT_URL + "=" + music.mContentURL;
            String coverImageURLData = "&" + KEY_COVER_IMAGE_URL + "=" + music.mCoverImageURL;
            String deviceIDData = "&" + KEY_DEVICE_ID + "=" + mDeviceID;
            String duration = "&" + KEY_DURATION + "=" + Long.toString(music.mDuration);
            String timestamp = "&" + KEY_TIMESTAMP + "=" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
            String  titleData = "&" + KEY_TITLE + "=" + music.mTitle.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            String typeData = "&" + KEY_TYPE + "=" + music.mType;
            
            String dataArrayString = contentURL + coverImageURLData + deviceIDData + duration + timestamp + titleData + typeData;
            
            String key = "&" + KEY_KEY + "=" + KEY;
            String sign = "&" + KEY_SIGN + "=" + Utilities.getMD5String(dataArrayString + key);
            
            String parametersURL = dataArrayString + sign;

            try 
            {
                handleHttpResponse(mConnectionManager.get(URL_MAIN + URL_ADD_MUSIC + parametersURL), REQUEST_CODE_ADD_MUSIC);
            } 
            
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                
                mListener.onServerRequestFail(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Here is the code of Http GET:

```
public String get(String urlString) throws IOException
    {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Get url string is " + urlString);
        
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
     
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Response code from GET: " + responseCode);
        
        if(responseCode == RESPONSE_OK)
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            reader.close();
            
            return response.toString();
        }
        
        else
        {
            return ERROR_NO_RESPONSE;
        }
    }
```

- I tried checking the `defaultCharset`, which is "UTF-8" for all phones tested.

How can I solve this? Please help. Many Thanks

------------ Tried URLEncoder.encode(music.mTitle.replaceAll("\s", ""), "UTF-8") ----------------

Here's the Log:

```
08-06 15:53:08.852: V/HttpConnectionManager(15061): Get url string is http://115.28.6.88:7100/cgi-bin/v1/music_add?content_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group6/M09/1E/0B/wKgDg1UrI8iw-rGzAAyaxOKiDrc706.mp3&cover_image_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group6/M00/1E/18/wKgDg1UrJp7TMEMMAAP5a37TPkE290_mobile_small.jpg&dev_id=test101&duration=103&timestamp=1438847588&title=%E3%80%8Ayouaremysunshine%E3%80%8B%EF%BC%8D%E5%BC%A0%E9%9D%93%E9%A2%96%EF%BC%88%E7%94%B5%E5%BD%B1%E3%80%8A%E4%BD%95%E4%BB%A5%E7%AC%99%E7%AE%AB%E9%BB%98%E3%80%8B%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E6%8F%92%E6%9B%B2&type=type_habit&sign=f7b8c5a0cb1fceb32a54b428311744ad
08-06 15:53:08.902: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(15061): <ConfigWindowMatch:2252>: Format RGBA_8888.
08-06 15:53:19.692: V/HttpConnectionManager(15061): Response code from GET: 200
08-06 15:53:19.692: V/DetailManager(15061): Handled http response is {"retcode": 100004, "retinfo": "check sign fail, request_sign:[F7B8C5A0CB1FCEB32A54B428311744AD], mysign:[537721D351DF6C8B40C62C4F8672EADF], mysign_src_nokey:[content_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group6/M09/1E/0B/wKgDg1UrI8iw-rGzAAyaxOKiDrc706.mp3&cover_image_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group6/M00/1E/18/wKgDg1UrJp7TMEMMAAP5a37TPkE290_mobile_small.jpg&dev_id=test101&duration=103&timestamp=1438847588&title=\u300ayouaremysunshine\u300b\uff0d\u5f20\u9753\u9896\uff08\u7535\u5f71\u300a\u4f55\u4ee5\u7b19\u7bab\u9ed8\u300b\u82f1\u6587\u63d2\u66f2&type=type_habit]"}
08-06 15:53:19.702: V/AudioFragment(15061): Server request failed: check sign fail, request_sign:[F7B8C5A0CB1FCEB32A54B428311744AD], mysign:[537721D351DF6C8B40C62C4F8672EADF], mysign_src_nokey:[content_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group6/M09/1E/0B/wKgDg1UrI8iw-rGzAAyaxOKiDrc706.mp3&cover_image_url=http://fdfs.xmcdn.com/group6/M00/1E/18/wKgDg1UrJp7TMEMMAAP5a37TPkE290_mobile_small.jpg&dev_id=test101&duration=103&timestamp=1438847588&title=《youaremysunshine》－张靓颖（电影《何以笙箫默》英文插曲&type=type_habit]
```

Comment: What happens if you URL encode your URL parameters?

Comment: I tried that too. Plenty %E%A%20 would be added to the URL. Then the server would return "sign check failed".

Comment: `%E%A%20` doesn't look like a correct encoding. Try, for each variable, something like: `String titleData = "&" + KEY_TITLE + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(music.mTitle.replaceAll("\\s", ""), "UTF-8");`

Comment: If you don't URL encode, how do you think you will deal with song titles containing &?

Comment: And assuming that your "sign check failed" is on the basis of checking the parts of your string, make sure that you are actually comparing like-for-like. For instance, is the server Url-decoding the parameters first?

Comment: @Andy Turner without using URL encode. The code works fine. But only for Samsung phone. For the other 3 phones, as long as there is Chinese characters, the method does not work

Comment: @Andy Turner I ll have to ask the one who set up the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Thanks to @Andy Turner, and @lorenzo-s for the tips in the comment.

My mistake is that I encoded the string to UTF-8 before getting the MD5 checksum. I noticed that when I send the request(URLEncoded) to the server, the response containing the title is correct. The error was only about the MD5 sign check.

The correct way is to get the MD5 checksum first without encoding the title parameter. Then before appending the title parameter to the URL String, convert it to UTF-8.

Thank you @Andy Turner for reminding me that I have to deal with the "&" in the parameter.